Tx on Solana not working despite having Jito and really high tx fee
Does anyone know what we are doing wrong? Our tx's just keep failing over and over again, even though our fees are the same as on other platforms like Phantom etc, our instructions are also almost identical, and we are even using jito with a super high tip, but still tx's keep failing over and over again.
here is how our tx looks like... (one that actually went through, while most of them failed)
https://solscan.io/tx/2KDjN8R5M87iiMDtwpjKmDkSfR2PiX7FkmL2cEpDaKjGXrJVgSKCvsQytgAtXxQ6rc8xnM1eb5TZyMSsR44RP7Gs
then we swapped the same token, from a different platform and there it works everytime: https://solscan.io/tx/mcESbySUL4v9m53AZm6en2ssTGfhCBhZe2x5tt5RgYoQxgYzcU8jqYJsRPXYS6pa9RmnXbnnxwEB7sXsMo2nHDx
so then we have set our sol fee to 0.0006 and jito tip to + 0.0003 ... so it should seem that every transaction should work -> but almost all of them fail over and over again!

Do you consider changing a node provider? Give a chance to Chainstack Solana trader nodes.
